# Using nix to build haskell project without split object files

Tags: haskell, ghc, nix

In [project 3](https://github.com/Gabriel439/haskell-nix/blob/429d98c04afd51b2ff4ba57da937a37db9382faa/project3/README.md) of Gabriel Gonzalez's tutorial on building haskell projects with nix, he writes:

> By default, these libraries are compiled with GHC's `-fsplit-objs` flag to enable split object files, which reduces the library size but increases the compile time. This is another reason why I recommend building the root project using cabal during development because by default cabal won't compile with split objects and will therefore build faster. However, `-fsplit-objs` is a good default when Nix builds the project, so you don't need to change this setting.

What isn't mentioned is how to make nix build your haskell project without `-fsplit-objs`. In my case, I have a backend project (built with GHC), a frontend project (built with GHCJS), and a shared project (built with both). Rebuilds of the shared project are somewhat common, so being able to turn off `-fsplit-objs` would save me a lot compilation time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `enableDeadCodeElimination=false` in your mkDerivation.